# How to prove result of applying filter to Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

A function f applied is applied to the Cartesian product of the set $
s = \{a,b\}
$ :

```
f(a,a) , f(a,b) , f(b,a) , f(b,b)
```

I think it's ok to ignore the output of the function f except to say that the output of f is commutative in terms of its arguments : `f(a,b) == f(b,a)`

for a set $
s = \{a,b,\,c\}
$

the possible functions are :

```
f(a,a),f(b,b),f(c,c),f(a,b),f(a,c),f(b,a),f(b,b),f(c,a),f(c,b)
```

Of interest here is `f(a,b) , (f(a,c) , f(b,c)` -> 3 comparisons

Is there a theorem or proof that describes

> if n=2 then 1 comparison required, if n=3 then 3 comparison required ?

This is my approach so far but I'm unable to show number of comparisons required for set of size n :

For set s of size n there exists $n^2$ pairs, to find 'unique' comparison remove self comparisons. A self comparison is one where a pair contains same elements such as (a,a) , (b,b) .

If $s = \{a,b\}$ there are $2^2$ = 4 pairs. Remove self comparisons , self comparisons are of size n. In this case n=2 so $4^2-2=2$. There are two pairs but just one is of interest as f(a,b) , f(b,a) will yield the same result. I'm struggling how to describe that I can remove f(a,b) or f(b,a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you are looking for is known as the *binomial*. For any number $n$, the symbol
$$
\binom{n}{2}
$$
is the number of ways to pick two elements from a set of $n$ elements. So, as you observed,
$$
\binom{2}{2} = 2 \qquad \text{and}\qquad \binom{3}{2} = 3.
$$
You can prove that generally
$$
\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2},
$$
which tells you the number of "comparisons" there are.

Comment: how does $n(n-1) / 2$ relate to "binomial" ? Reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient does not mention the formula $n(n-1) / 2$ . Closest I found is this post http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/61212.html which describes $n(n-1) / 2$ in terms of number of connections but does not mention "binomial".

Comment: @blue-sky, more generally, numbers of the form $\binom{n}{k}$ are called binomials or binomial coefficients. You are looking at one special case, namely the case where $k = 2$.